# Proof that a function is Riemann integrable if for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a partition P such that: $U(P, f) − L(P, f) < \epsilon$

Tags: proof-explanation, riemann-integration, partitions-for-integration

I am working my way through the proof of the following: 
Let $f$ be bounded on [a,b]. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable if and only if for every $\epsilon$ there is a partition on $[a,b]$ such that: $0 \leq U(f,P) - L(f,P) \leq \epsilon$.
I have a question regarding the beginning of the proof:

Since $$\int_{a}^{b}f = \inf\{U(f,P)\}=\sup\{L(f,P)\}$$
there should exist two partitions $P_1$ and $P_2$ such that:
$$0\leq U(f,P_1)-\int_{a}^{b}f < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ and $$0 \leq \int_{a}^{b}f-L(f,P_2) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
Why do the partitions give those inequalities?

Comment: $\int_{a}^{b}f$ is defined to be the infimum of $U(f,P)$over all possible partitions. By the definition of infimum, you can find one partition, say P1, such that $U(f,P_1)$ is "as close to the infimum as you'd like", ie $U(f,P_1)-\int_{a}^{b}f < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Similarly, for supremum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\int_{a}^{b}f = inf\{U(f,P)\}$, we can keep finding partitions that such that $U(f,P)$ are closer and closer to $\int_{a}^{b}f$ approaching from above.  So choose a partition, call it $P_1$, such that it is closer than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ to $\int_{a}^{b}f$.  That means
$$ U(f,P_1) < \int_{a}^{b}f +\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
$$ \iff U(f,P_1) - \int_{a}^{b}f <\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Finally note that $U(f,P_1) \geq inf\{U(f,P)\}$, so
$$ 0 = \int_{a}^{b}f - \int_{a}^{b}f = inf\{U(f,P)\} -  \int_{a}^{b}f \leq U(f,P_1) - \int_{a}^{b}f <\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
$$ \iff 0 \leq U(f,P_1) - \int_{a}^{b}f <\frac{\epsilon}{2} $$

The argument is almost identical for $L(f,P)$ (except flipping some inequalities)

Comment: I see now, thank you very much.